# Send data to database after redirect (and popping out of iframe)

Tags: database, redirect

I am using $wpdb->insert to place form data into a custom database. There a multiple things happening, though. The page that sends the data to the database is caught in an iframe. I know how to get it out of the iframe, however, when I do, that is causing a redirect in addition to the initial redirect. How do I make sure the data is only sent once? I don't want two entries in the database because it is redirecting twice. Here's the important bits:

WPDB->insert part

```
if(isset($qualification, $first_name, $middle_initial, $last_name, $email, $street_address, $city, $state, $zip, $phone)) {


            global $wpdb;

             $wpdb->insert(
             'wp_mstops_user_info',
             array(

             "first_name" =>            $first_name,
             "middle_initial" =>        $middle_initial,
             "last_name" =>             $last_name,
             "email" =>                 $email,
             "street_address" =>        $street_address,
             "city" =>                  $city,
             "state" =>                 $state,
             "zipcode" =>               $zip,
             "phone" =>                 $phone,
             "qualification_data" =>    $qualification,
             "substudy_data" =>         $substudy_json    

           )
           ); 
    }
```

Pop out of an iframe part:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (top.location!= self.location) {
     top.location = self.location.href;
  }       
 </script>
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (as opposed to an edit) and then mark your post as the solution.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have added my solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up appending a string to the iframe break:

```
top.location = self.location.href + "&noframe=1";
```

Then checking for it.

```
if(isset($_GET['noframe']) && $_GET['noframe'] == 1)
```

Then I insert into the database.